# Use same color for all text

Tags: fonts, color

I saw other answers, but no one has achieved what I want.
I need to print my work, and I want all the text colors to be black.
I'm using packages that change's font color like \url{} or \cite{} and that's ok for digital PDF, but if I want to print it I would like them to be plain as the rest of the text.

I tried put

```
\begin{document}
\color{black}

...

\end{document}
```

But this doesn't work.

I use:

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[OC]{\leftmark} % all ODD pages will have the leftmark-->capitolo
\fancyhead[EC]{\rightmark} % all EVEN pages will have the rightmark-->sezione
\cfoot{\thepage}
\end{document}
```

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you checked the documentation of `hyperref`? Have you tried option `hidelinks`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I solved the problem changing `colorlinks=false` in  `\usepackage[ colorlinks=false,breaklinks]{hyperref}`. Now not only `\url` but also `\cite{}` and `\ref{}` are not colored. Haven't thought of it, I'm at the very first use of Latex. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments ...